# Javascript Multiplication Table Based On User Input

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I have a program where the user enters two inputs, and then when the display button is pressed, the multiplication table within the parameters of those two numbers is displayed. However, when I press the button, nothing is displayed.

```
    <span style = "font-size:15px">First Number: </span><input type = "text" id = "first_num" style = "font-size:18px"> <br /><br />
    <span style = "font-size:15px">Second Number: </span><input type = "text" id = "second_num" style = "font-size:18px"> <br /><br />
    <button type = "button" onclick = "display()">Display</button> <br /><br />
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    var f_num = document.getElementById("first_num").value;
    var s_num = document.getElementById("second_num").value;
    function display() {
    for (i=1;i<f_num + 1;i++) {
            for (j=1;j<s_num + 1;j++) {
            if (j == 10) {
            document.write(i+"*" +j +"=" +(i*j) + "<br /><br />")
            } else {
            document.write(i+"*" +j +"=" +(i*j) + "  |  ")
            }
            }
    } 
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

you should set your variable within the function.in your current code they are being set when the first time script is getting executed and at that time they have blank value.

Correct code will be.

```
 function display() {
  var f_num = parseInt(document.getElementById("first_num").value);
  var s_num = parseInt(document.getElementById("second_num").value);
 for (i=1;i<f_num + 1;i++) {
        for (j=1;j<s_num + 1;j++) {
        if (j == 10) {
        document.write(i+"*" +j +"=" +(i*j) + "<br /><br />");
        } else {
        document.write(i+"*" +j +"=" +(i*j) + "  |  ");
        }
        }
} 
}
```

You can check things on the below plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/kgWaEG1ZvgST0RclvV2l?p=preview

Comment: Yes but for some strange reason if i input 1 in both boxes, it gives me a ten by ten times table

Comment: Also it just sprouts out a bunch of weird multiplication tables when I enter numbers.

Comment: that is happening because the value you are getting in f_num and s_num are strings. I have updated the above answer and corrected the logic.